# Training an AI to categorise a variable number of features into a set number of categories

Tags: machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

I would like to create an AI to detect text in an image containing a string of one or more characters from a list of 100 possible characters. I would like the AI to output a string containing what it predicts the text is, as well as a confidence value for each character in it.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to have a variable number of outputs.

I have figured out how to detect a single character by finding a confidence value for each possible character, but I would like for it to find this for each character in an image containing multiple images.

The only solution I can think of is to have it return a binary number for each letter, the same length as the string. Each `1` would represent the character being present in that position. However, I don't know how to get a confidence value from this.

---

**What I have:**
This is the AI currently have. It takes an image containing a single character and outputs a confidence value for each possible character.

**Example:**
Input:
An image containing the letter `B`

Output:

| Letter | Confidence |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0.05 |
| B | 0.80 |
| C | 0.05 |

etc...

**What I want:**
I would like it to take an image containing multiple characters and output a confidence value for each possible character for each character in the image.

**Example 1: (3 character string)**
Input:
An image containing the string `ABC`

Output:

| Letter | Character 1 | Character 2 | Character 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.80 | 0.05 | 0.05 |
| B | 0.05 | 0.80 | 0.05 |
| C | 0.05 | 0.05 | 0.80 |

etc...

**Example 2: (2 Character string)**
Input:
An image containing the string `BA`

Output:

| Letter | Character 1 | Character 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.05 | 0.85 |
| B | 0.80 | 0.05 |
| C | 0.05 | 0.05 |

etc...

Notice how the length of the output array changes depending on the input.

---

This is my first time creating an AI in python, so I haven't really used sci-kit learn or Keras. I'm fine with using either, however my current solution uses Keras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate your problem into two steps:

**Step 1:**
Find all characters.

**Step 2:**
Crop each character from step one and predict which kind of character it is.

Note: There are approaches which combines everything into one step (YOLO architecture can possibly do that, however, since step 2 is already solved and you are a beginner, it might be easier to understand and debug if you keep the steps separate for the moment).

You could use a very simple U-net architecture, to find the position of characters. [Here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/oxford_pets_image_segmentation/) it is explained for keras. The result will be a heatmap, which has high values for areas containing a character. These heatmaps can be viewed as images and allow easy interpreation. You can then find peaks (=the center of a character), cut the area around the peak (e.g. 64x64px) and feed each peak into your step-2-network. Peaks can be easily found with [this procedure](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_peak_local_max.html). The `skimage` function `peak_local_max` allows to define thresholds and the minimum distance to the border and to other peaks. Note, your step-2-network expects images of the same size (e.g. 64x64px), so when cropping characters close to the border you will need to pad with zeros to give it the needed size.

**edit** The training data for step-1-network is a black images with white circles at the centers of your characters. The training data for step-2-network is a centered, fixed-sized character image with a one-hot-encoded label of the character it is. Here it might be useful to add an additional class for "Not a character" to correct mistakes that step-1-network makes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand how to fix my problem now. The only issue is that the training data I am using only contains sentences, and not the locations of characters.

Are there any datasets you know of that I can use to train this, or tools that can find the characters in the training data automatically?

This is for school, so I am fine with using someone else's AI to create training data, but I cannot use someone else's AI by itself.

Comment: you could post an example image? I guess these trainubg images are easily generated? just take a background (white?) and write some characters on it at random positions with open cv library. remember those positions to generate labels, too.

Comment: imgaug is a nice library that alliws you to augment image and label accordingly. for example: when rotating or shifting the inpute image the label is rotated and shifted accordingly. Changes in color, however; are not performes on labels etc